# Clone Selectize while loading from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a selector with Selectize.js, and I want the users to be able to clone it like here: [Selectize.js ComboBox: Cloning and Destroying](https://mariolurig.com/coding/selectize-js-combobox-cloning-destroying/)
. Also, I want the original and the clones to load data from my database with AJAX.

At the moment I can load from database, and I can clone the selector; but if I do this, the new one clear the value stored of the preceeding selector.

My HTML is this:

```
<div id="clone_me_id">
    <div class="clone_me_class">
        <select class="selector_class">
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id='cloner_button'>Add another</button>
</div>
```

And here are my scripts. The main one that calls Selectize.js and ejecute a php to get the data from the database:

```
<script>
    function selectizeme(){
    $('.selector_class').selectize({
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'name',
        searchField: 'name',
        options: [],
        persist: false,
        maxItems: 2,
        create: true,
        sortField: 'text',
        createOnBlur: true,
        sortField: 'text',
        load: function(query, callback) {
            if(!query.length>2) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php', //relative url to the php script that loads the data and send it in JSON format
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name: query,
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    callback(res);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And the scripts that clone the selector

```
<script>
    // When cloner_button button is clicked
    $('#cloner_button').on('click',function(){
        $('.selector_class').each(function(){ // do this for every select with the 'selector_class' class
        if ($(this)[0].selectize) { // requires [0] to select the proper object
            var value = $(this).val(); // store the current value of the select/input
            $(this)[0].selectize.destroy(); // destroys selectize()
            $(this).val(value);  // set back the value of the select/input
        }
    });
    $('#clone_me_id .clone_me_class:first')
    .clone() // copy
    .insertAfter('#clone_me_id .clone_me_class:last'); // where
    selectizeme(); // reinitialize selectize on all .selector_class
});
$(function(){ // same as $(document).ready()
    selectizeme(); // selectize all .selector_class
});
</script>
```

And this is my php for the query to the database (there is no problem here)

```
<?php
$search =  $_POST['name'];
$connection = new mysqli('localhost','***','***','***');
$sql = "SELECT a.id AS id, a.name AS name
FROM user a
WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " .mysqli_error($connection));
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    $rows[] = "{ \"id\": \"$id\",\"name\": \"$name\"}";
}
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
echo "[\n" .join(",\n", $rows) ."\n]";
?>
```

Anyone knows how can I avoid the cloner to delete the value of the previous selector? Any help will be welcomed!

N.

---

Edit:

Ok, I ended with a solution adding this lines:

```
var select = $(this)[0].childNodes[0]; // store the childNodes (options) of the select
var clone = select.cloneNode(true); // clone the stored options
$(this)[0].appendChild(clone); // append the cloned options to the new select
```

To the script that clones the selector, like this:

```
<script>
    // When cloner_button button is clicked
    $('#cloner_button').on('click',function(){
        $('.selector_class').each(function(){ // do this for every select with the 'selector_class' class
        if ($(this)[0].selectize) { // requires [0] to select the proper object
            var value = $(this).val(); // store the current value of the select/input
            var select = $(this)[0].childNodes[0]; // store the childNodes (options) of the select
            var clone = select.cloneNode(true); // clone the stored options
            $(this)[0].selectize.destroy(); // destroys selectize()
            $(this)[0].appendChild(clone); // append the cloned options to the new select
            $(this).val(value);  // set back the value of the select/input
        }
    });
</script>
```

This doesn't work for multiple selectors, and also repeats the value of the last selector in the new one. But that's a beginning!

N.

Comment: Be a good StackOverflow citizen and mark the answer as 'correct' (green check).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot… done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a snippet (that others can play with) goes a long way. Unlike the example on my site, which has preset OPTIONS, your select doesn't have any. The code sample is based on EXISTING options. In your case, you don't have any, so the original SELECT doesn't have any options to set once selectize is destroyed. You will need to add in Javascript to do that:

```
var value = $(this).val(); // store the current value of the select/input
$(this)[0].selectize.destroy(); // destroys selectize()
// CREATE the OPTION
$(this).val(value);  // set back the value of the select/input
```

That's my best guess.

Comment: Great, thank you! I have just edited my question with the lines I added to the script. This is not the perfect solution, but it works…